# Form validation - Multiple emails

Tags: html, forms, angularjs, email

Hi I have a form with a text area that holds multiple emails addresses.  How can I validate this in AngularJS, right now it says it is invalid when there is more than one emails. The emails will be comma separated.

```
<form name="testForm" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
     <textarea type="email" multiple rows="3" name="emailInput" placeholder="Email Addresses" ng-model="user.email" required></textarea>    
     <button type="submit" ng-disabled="testForm.$invalid">Email</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking a look at the **[source (version 1.2.16)](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js)**, it is easy to find out how the validation of a single email takes place:

```
// This is the regular expression used to validate the value
var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i;

// A helper function to call $setValidity and return the value / undefined,
// a pattern that is repeated a lot in the input validation logic.
function validate(ctrl, validatorName, validity, value){
  ctrl.$setValidity(validatorName, validity);
  return validity ? value : undefined;
}

// Excerpt from the `input[type="email"]` directive
var emailValidator = function(value) {
  return validate(ctrl, 'email', ctrl.$isEmpty(value) || EMAIL_REGEXP.test(value), value);
};

ctrl.$formatters.push(emailValidator);
ctrl.$parsers.push(emailValidator);
```

---

So, you could make your own directive that validates multiple, comma-searated emails in a similar fashion:

```
app.directive('multipleEmails', function () {
  // Constants
  var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i;

  // DDO
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: multipleEmailsPostLink
  };

  // Function Definitions
  function isValidEmail(email) {
    return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email.trim());
  }

  function multipleEmailsPostLink(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {
    modelCtrl.$formatters.push(multipleEmailsValidator);
    modelCtrl.$parsers.push(multipleEmailsValidator);

    // Helpers
    function multipleEmailsValidator(value) {
      return validateAll(modelCtrl, 'multipleEmails', value);
    }
  }

  function validateAll(ctrl, validatorName, value) {
    var validity = ctrl.$isEmpty(value) || value.split(',').every(isValidEmail);

    ctrl.$setValidity(validatorName, validity);

    return validity ? value : undefined;
  }
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/3YyXu/)**.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. Hopefully this is added to the Angular core soon. FYI JShint will complain about the semiconol on the ```multipleEmailsValidator``` function (depending on how strict you have it set)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty way to do what you need. In your HTML:

```
<textarea ng-change="validateEmails()" ng-model="user.email" ng-class="user.validation.email.isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid'">
<div class="errorPanel" ng-show="!user.validation.email.isValid">{{ validation.email.message }}</div>
```

Alternatively, instead of ng-change you can use ng-blur so that the textarea does not become 'invalid' as the user is typing in emails. I'll leave that up to you, though. Add some CSS styling for textarea.valid, textarea.invalid, div.errorPanel.

And in your controller:

```
user.validation = {};
user.validation.email = {
  message: '',
  isValid: true
};

$scope.validateEmails = function() {
  var emails = $scope.user.email.split(',');

  var isValid = true;
  for (var i = 0; isValid && i < emails.length; i++) {
    if (!validateEmail(emails[i])) {
      isValid = false;
      user.validation.email.isValid = false;
      user.validation.email.message = 'Email ' + emails[i] + ' does not appear to be a proper email';
    }
  }

}

function validateEmail() {
  // use whatever email validation function you want
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is clearly not the "Angular way" to do it, but a little heads-up: the FomrController will add the necessary classes automatically, so you don't need to do it manually (e.g. ng-invalid, ng-valid, ng-valid-required etc)