# Angular $scope.$watch returns undefined when the value contains coma(",") or arobase("@")

Tags: angularjs, scope, watch

The scope.$watch returns undefined when the value observed contains a coma (,) or an arobase (@).
Could you explain me why?

I try to make a snippet, but for some reason I can't even manage to make the scope.$watch working - but it works on my local project...

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('mainController',
        ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {
              
                $scope.mailToAdd = {email: ""};
                
                $scope.$watch('mailToAdd.email', function(val){
                    console.log(val);
                   $scope.watched= val;

                });
 }]
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
   <br/>
  Value to observe: <input ng-model="mailToAdd.email" type="email" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Value watched: <input ng-model="watched" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `scope.$watch`. It is because your model itself goes null because you have input type as `email` and comma is an invalid character for an email, as the data is invalid it will go blank (You can test this by printing the value of ng-model on the view `{{mailToAdd.email}}`). You may want to have to convert it to textbox. Or you may have to  set `ng-model-options` `allowInvalid` flag to true. But with this if you want to validate email you may [have to perform custom validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066295/form-validation-multiple-emails).

i.e

```
 ng-model-options="{'allowInvalid':true}
```

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('mainController',
        ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {
              
                $scope.mailToAdd = {email: ""};
                
                $scope.$watch('mailToAdd.email', function(val){
                    console.log(val);
                   $scope.watched= val;

                });
 }]
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
   <br/>
  Value to observe: <input ng-model="mailToAdd.email" ng-model-options="{'allowInvalid':true}" type="email" />
  {{mailToAdd.email}}
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Value watched: <input ng-model="watched" type="text" />
</div>
```